# Import data from SharePoint to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sharepoint, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using Oracle SQL Developer as a tool, and I wish to import data from Sharepoint list to my SQL server. I wonder if there is any convenient way to do so?

In Access, this task is quite simple, but one sad thing is that I need to use SQL server.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is the MySQL Dump Web Part for SharePoint lists at www.bendsoft.com, http://www.bendsoft.com/downloads/sharepoint-web-parts/mysql-dump/. It's based on the Camelot ADO.NET Connector for SharePoint. Send them a message and see if they are willing to port the web part to be SQL Server compatible! If not it's a piece of cake to write something of your own with the .NET Connector.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know you can open your standard sharepoint list with Access ?

Move the tables in an Access database to a SharePoint site and link to them
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-integrating-data-between-access-and-a-sharepoint-site-HA010131463.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If SSIS is an option, take a look at the SharePoint List Source and Destination Sample in the [Microsoft SQL Server Community Samples: Integration Services](http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex.

Answer (score 0):

I need clarity about the question's statement:'*I wish to import data from Sharepoint list to my SQL server.*'do you mean 'import' or 'export'?  I believe,you mean 'export' here. If you mean to export data from sharepoint to sql server,below are steps:

The export process exports only the columns and rows contained in the list’s current view. If none of the views contain the data that you want to export, then you must create a new view to meet your needs. Alternatively, you can choose one of the existing views, export the list to a spreadsheet, and then delete the unwanted data.

Actions > Export to SpreadSheet.
Save the Excel file.
Open your SQL database with SQL Management Studio.
Right click on your database > Tasks > Import Data.
Select your Excel file as the source, and specific table as destination.
Fill all other needed options.
Click finish.